# Fork Join pool hangs

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, fork-join, forkjoinpool

The case is that an application hangs infinitely from time to time.

Seems that the bug sits in the following snippet:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(1); // parallelism = 1

List<String> entries = ...;

pool.submit(() -> {

    entries.stream().parallel().forEach(entry -> {
        // An I/O op.
        ...
    });

}).get();
```

Thread `pool-4-thread-1` that executes the code freezes on `get()`:

```
"pool-4-thread-1" #35 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00002b42e4013800 nid=0xb7d1 in Object.wait() [0x00002b427b72f000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:367)
        - locked <0x00000000e08b68b8> (a java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
...other app methods
```

One can assume that the task passed to `submit()` executes too long.

But surprisingly there is no `ForkJoinPool-N-worker-N` occurrences in the thread dump, so looks like the pool doesn't perform any computations!

How is that possible? If no tasks are executed by the pool, why `pool-4-thread-1` thread waits inside `get()`?

**P.S.** I know that it's not recommended to execute I/O-related tasks in `ForkJoinPool`, but still interested in the root of the problem.

**Update.** When `parallelism` is set to value greater than 1, no problems are detected.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493399/forkjoinpool-parallelism-1-deadlock

Comment: What other thread(s) does the thread dump show? `.get()` is obviously still waiting for some computation.

Comment: @manouti full stacktrace can be found here: http://paste.ix/QS02o

Comment: @Ivan thanks. Seems that the issue in the given question has been already solved for my JVM version.

Comment: @Aliaxander maybe not all cases were fixed and you need to raise a bug for OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `parallelism = N` where `N > 1` solved the problem.

Strange thing but seems that there is some bug in `ForkJoinPool` similar to what is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493399/forkjoinpool-parallelism-1-deadlock).